# Please help me identify this partially assembled set, red and 2 large propellers?

Tags: set-identification

A sweet neighbor kid handed down his LEGO collection to us. I’ve been able to find quite a few sets by searching Google, but this one has me stumped.

[image]

Comment: In most cases if it has vessel ID (like the number on wings) is the part number of the set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [8060-1: Typhoon Turbo Sub](https://brickset.com/sets/8060-1/Typhoon-Turbo-Sub)

[image]